# XML code inserts same cname twice in database rather than inserting 'USA' and 'UK'

Tags: php, xml

The below code is to use XML in PHP to insert 'cname' field into 'tbl_country'. I want to add 'USA' and 'UK' respectively however the code inserts 'USA' twice instead. 'cid' is the primary key auto_increment field in 'tbl_country'.

```
<?php
    $xmlData =<<< END
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Country>
      <cname>USA</cname>
      <cname>UK</cname>
    </Country>
    END;


    //xml code for database connection        
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlData) or die("ERROR: Cannot create SimpleXML object");
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin", "regdb") or die ("ERROR: Cannot connect");

    /* Assumes that the number of IDs = number of countries */
    $size = sizeOf($xml->cname);
    $i = 0; //index

    /* Add each country to the database
    while($i != $size) 
    {
        //echo $xml->id[$i]; //Test
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_country(cname) VALUES('$xml->cname')";
        $con->query($sql);
        $i++; //increment index
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Incrementing `$i` does not affect xml values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead using `for` and some additional variables (`$i`, `$size`) - use `foreach`:

```
/* Assumes that the number of IDs = number of countries */
//$size = sizeOf($xml->cname);
//$i = 0; //index

/* Add each country to the database */
foreach ($xml->cname as $item) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_country(cname) VALUES('$item')";
    $con->query($sql);
}
```

And of course consider moving to **prepared statements** with your queries.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the index as well:

```
$cnames = $xml->cname;
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_country(cname) VALUES('$cnames[$i]')";
```

In that way, you can iterate through every values. Otherwise only the first matching tag's value will be returned. Which is what happening in your case.